# How to "unclip" or draw a dynamical arc (circular countdown) around an image we want to fully display

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I am tryng to draw a circular countdown around an image (an `arc` which will decrease its `end angle` above an other `arc` which will still static).

I have to `clip` after drawing the static and the dynamic arc to draw the image into it.
But the problem is, the image is drawing into the dynamical arc (so we don't fully see it).

Here is the code and a JsFiddle:

```
<canvas id="test" width="230px", height="230px"></canvas>    
var ctx = document.getElementById('test').getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(115, 115, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 15; 
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'back'; 
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(115, 115, 100, 0, 1*Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 15; 
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'; 
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.clip();

    ctx.drawImage(this, 15, 15, 200, 200);
}, true);
img.src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3309741408/eff94615a3653c01a9d5a178ced7fbb5.jpeg";
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqs2y/)

**UPDATE:**
Here is something very close about what i am looking for: [JsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/tqs2y/4/), except the red `arc` appears in a very bad way...

Comment: is this something like this you're after ? http://jsfiddle.net/tqs2y/1/

Comment: @GameAlchemist Not really but almost, i just want the "border" (the arc) to play the countdown, like in a poker game, you can see the user's avatar but a circular countdown is playing around its avatar when it's his turn to play (whithout showing/hidding the image).

Comment: @GameAlchemist Here is something very close about what i am looking for: jsfiddle.net/tqs2y/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Order matters

You are very close and only need to change orders of things a little (I hope I understood your intention correctly):

I would recommend to do the clipping with a full circle first because this won't obscure what is drawn on top of it (if you clip later you might clip of the arc as well - unless you want to do this).

## Set and reset a clipping mask

Resetting a clipping mask turns out to be a bit "unstable", ie. setting a new path and a rectangle that covers the entire canvas. So the better choice in this case for the moment is to rely on the `save`/`restore` approach to reset it:

```js
/// backup current state of canvas
ctx.save();

/// create clipping mask, a full circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(115, 115, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();

/// then draw the image that you want to clip
ctx.drawImage(this, 15, 15, 200, 200);

/// remove clipping by restoring canvas state to previous
ctx.restore();
```

## Unbound overlays

Now the image is clipped into a circle you can draw your arcs without considering or re-calculating line widths etc. in relation to image as they are not bound to clipping:

```js
/// draw the arcs on top
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(115, 115, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.lineWidth = 15; 
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'; 
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(115, 115, 100, 0, 1*Math.PI, true);
ctx.lineWidth = 15; 
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'; 
ctx.stroke();
```

**[MODIFIED FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/tqs2y/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

**You can use context.save / context.restore to control your clipping activities**

[image][image]

This is one way to do it:

```js
// Outer circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 40, 0, 2 * PI, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.lineWidth=20;
ctx.strokeStyle="black";
ctx.stroke();

// Inner sweeping arc
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 40, startRadians, endRadians, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.stroke();

// Clipped avatar
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 30, 0, 2 * PI, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();
ctx.drawImage(avatar, 0, 0, avatar.width, avatar.height, 150-40, 150-40, 80, 80);
ctx.restore();
```

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/j96yy/

```js
$(function() {
  var avatarUrl = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/avatar.jpg';
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var fps = 60;

  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / fps);
      };
  })();


  // Set context styles
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff9944';
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';

  // Set var's to control arc
  var PI = Math.PI;
  var startRadians = -PI / 2;
  var endRadians = -PI / 2;
  var tickRadians = 2 * PI / 60 / 2; // 60 ticks per circle
  var continue_animation = true;

  // Load avatar image, then animate
  var avatar = loadImage(avatarUrl, animate);
  
  // Compute size and location of the avatar.
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius  = canvas.width * 0.33;

  // Animate an arc inside a circle
  function animate() {
    // Update
    endRadians += tickRadians;
    if (endRadians > 2 * PI) {
      continue_animation = false;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    // Outer circle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * PI, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = radius / 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#444444';
    ctx.stroke();

    // Inner sweeping arc
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startRadians, endRadians, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = radius / 4;
    ctx.strokeStyle = calcArcStateColor(endRadians);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Clipped avatar
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius * 0.75, 0, 2 * PI, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 0, 0, avatar.width, avatar.height, centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    ctx.restore();

    // Request new frame
    if (continue_animation) {
      requestAnimFrame(animate);
    }
  }

  $('#go').click(function() {
    endRadians = -PI / 2;
    continue_animation = true;
    animate();
  });

  animate();
});

function loadImage(url, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    if (callback) callback();
  };
  img.src = url;
  return img;
}

function calcArcStateColor(radians) {
  if      (radians > Math.PI * 1.75) return '#00DD44';
  else if (radians > Math.PI * 1.00) return '#FFDD44';
  else if (radians > Math.PI * 0.25) return '#FF8844';
  else                               return '#FF4444';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
  padding: 20px;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button id="go">Animate</button><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks very interesting ! I finally did it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/tqs2y/7/ but i will look further how to play with save/restore way

Comment: Nice touch with the green/amber/red arc! Glad you got it sorted.  BTW, you might look at this article which shows how to use requestAnimationFrame + setTimeout instead of setInterval.  RAF provides much better performance and is the way web animation is headed: http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/

Answer (score 0):

save your context before clip  and use the restore method whereever you want to unclip needed